# Is there any tool or any way to get all processes which are queued in windows?

Tags: windows, central-processing-unit, performance-monitoring, diagnostic

Is there any tool or any way to get all processes which are queued in windows? i have value of CPU Queue very high
i have few apps running on server. the CPU Queue continue to reach sometimes 3000, while the overall cpu usage is very low, mostly less than 50%, but queue keeps increasing and i have no idea how to know which processes are queued and why. what could be any tool to check it? or its not possible to get queued processes and why they are queued?

Comment: What is a "queued" process?

Comment: @bviktor I believe the requestor is looking at perfmon, \\System\\Processor Queue Length, which displays the number of ready threads waiting to execute.

Comment: @farhan that's a lot of threads.  What do you see in Task Manager->Details when you add a column for Threads?  While watching that counter, can you stop each app in turn and see whether the queue empties?  If a process can be identified, it should easier figuring out why.

Comment: Like the other comments indicated, your question in this current state lacks of important information such as what application(s) is running (web server or database server?). Performance monitor can only show you so much, and it will require further analysis (such as performance profiling or hang dump analysis) to dig further.

Comment: @Maurkov: yes, i am asking about Processor Queue length. how to know which processes are there in queue

Comment: Processes aren't queued. This may be more accurately described as *threads* that are queued for a *processor*. Given the number of context switches that occur on a system with thousands of processes, a snapshot of all queued threads for all processes is unlikely to be meaningful. However it is fairly easy to recreate this scenario in Windows. It is even easier to recreate on platforms that have throttling, such as most cloud providers.

Comment: @GregAskew: but how to know which one they are . thread processes, which are they. what are they. how to link them to processes

Comment: @LexLi : its for any application. processor does not rely on process type of its nature. the point is how to get the processes in queeu

Comment: Have you tried the suggesion to use pslist? The -d switch includes all threads. It has the PID on a separate line, but it should be fairly easy to parse that and put it all out to another file with PID+Thread detail on a single line. You would be looking for threads in the Wait::Queue state.

Answer (score -1):

This is a tool I used in the past. It says it supports windows 10 upwards,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools

pslist will give you a break down of each process